# Override console.log to format numbers

Tags: javascript, debugging, console.log

I often need to log numbers to the console during javascript debugging but I don't need all the decimal places.

```
console.log("PI is", Math.PI); // PI is 3.141592653589793
```

How can I override console.log to always format numbers with 2 decimal places?

NB: Overriding `Number.prototype.toString()` does not achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overriding inbuilt stuff is a very very bad idea. May write your own small function as a shortcut:

```js
const log = (...args)=> console.log(...args.map(el =>
     typeof el === "number"? Number(el.toFixed(2)) : el
));

log("Math.PI is ", Math.PI);
```

Comment: Better than OP answering his own question :)

Comment: I just took the liberty to make a snippet.

Comment: A final glanzing would be to convert the arguments back to numbers before logging.

Comment: @teemu shure ;)

Comment: Is answering your own question frowned upon @JeremyThille ? I thought it was welcomed. Especially when I'd spent some time googling the issue and finding nothing, solving it myself.

Comment: Oh no no, not at all. What you did is fine. But this answer is even better, that's it :) It's just more elegant. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a monkey patch for `console.log`, which is not advisable, usually.

```js
void function () {
    var log = console.log;
    console.log = function () {
        log.apply(log, Array.prototype.map.call(arguments, function (a) {
            return typeof a === 'number'
                ? +a.toFixed(2)
                : a;
            }));
        };
    }();

console.log("PI is", Math.PI);  // PI is 3.14
console.log("A third is", 1/3); // A third is 0.33
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a quick shortcut function which is easy to type and formats numbers:

```
    const dp = function() {
        let args = [];
        for (let a in arguments) args.push(typeof arguments[a] == "number"?arguments[a].toFixed(2):arguments[a])
        console.log.apply(console, args);
    }
```

Gives you:

dp("PI is", Math.PI); // PI is 3.14